Intel CPU frequency limited after a while under heavy multithreaded load
I have a Linux Mint system with an i5-13600 CPU and an all-in-one watercooler on a MSI MAG Z790 Tomahawk motherboard. I've noticed that when I put a heavy computational load on my system (like encoding videos, training ML models, ...) my cooling system starts to run in high speed and my CPU temperature goes up (to around 80°C) for a short time (like a minute). During this time, CPU-X reports a frequency of around 4,7 GHz. But soon the frequency drops to around 3,2 GHz and the temperature drops to 50°C (still running the same computation). I don't have a "k" CPU since I didn't mean to overclock.
But is this the intended behavior? Does that mean the CPU is not meant to run at 4,7 GHz for a longer period? And can if wanted to do that, would that be overclocking?

A system and CPU will throttle themselves as part of their overall cooling plan to protect the system from damage from heat. If whatever load you're running is more than the cooling system can handle at the higher frequency, the system will throttle itself.

Also keep in mind that there’s more to it than just CPU (core) temperature. There’s also power targets, and voltage regulator modules (VRMs) along the way that also generate lots of heat, …

I wasn't expecting it to be thermal throttling since it works fine at 80°C CPU core temperature. But maybe there are other components limiting it, thanks!

That CPU has a standard frequency of 2.7 GHz for Performance Cores, and 2.0 GHz for efficiency cores. The performance cores will go up to 5.0 GHz, and the efficiency cores up to 3.7 using TurboBoost, but only if the situation is right, so you should not consider Turbo speeds to be the real speed of the chip. There is also a concern about the threading, since you have cores running at different speeds (performance/efficiency) so some tasks using symetric mutli-threading across more than the number of performance cores may be simply stuck in a spin-wait pattern, awaiting the completion of others


I wasn't expecting it to be thermal throttling

The old classic concept of "thermal throttling" is a thing from the past. All modern CPUs/APUs nowadays include means to control operating conditions of all CPU/APU functional units, all under pretty sophisticated PMU (Power Management Unit). The system automatically controls ALL aspects of every core dynamically, which includes P-state continuous jumping/adjustment, wide range clock control/gating, appropriate voltage control (including dynamic voltage/clock boost) and power gating, and strictly enforce local (and global) TDP limits. All this happens dynamically and at relatively high rate (on a millisecond scale), each core operates at it's own frequency, so all reporting from SW-level tools are pretty much inaccurate and partially misleading. So, in some sense the processor is throttling, but not in old binary fashion (on-off), but in much more sophisticated gradual control loop, keeping processor safe and operational under nearly any load.
